# Not able to redirect IP,I am getting the error.So how can I solve it?

Tags: nginx, proxy

I want to use reverse proxy with Nginx to redirect/translate IP and port to some other IP and port. But I am getting the error. I have checked in a [site](https://hostingga.com/blog/) log. But I didn't gets the solution.